# npm install getting failed for angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm newbie to angular 2. From reading some resources I had done with the following steps for my angular 2 application.
1)Create a folder named "DemoThree".
2)From the command prompt taken a hit over "ng new ThirdApp"
ThirdApp is my application name. Even It got succeded.
Find the image below for successfully creation of application.[image: Success of application creation]

3)When I hit the command "npm start" I'm facing an error list in command prompt as like below image
[image: npm install error]

4)From the errors, I understood that I'm not getting package.json file. How could I get that file ?

I had seen lot of commands related to getting package.json file, of them one is one is by using npm init.
But when I tried with init. It's asking to provide me all the values of keys like description, version, name,script,dependencies.

How to resolve my error list from the prompt ?

5)After facing that error I thought that I need to install anguar cli which get all dependencies by using npm install -g @angular/cli
Got succeeded here.

6)Again I tried with npm install. No use faced the same poin 3 error image.

Please suggest me where I was doing mistake.

Comment: You need to change your directory `cd ThirdApp` before `npm start`

Comment: Instead use command `ng serve`

Comment: ng new creates a new directory, you need to `cd` into it

Comment: @ricky It helped me. Than you.   Can you pplese suggest me when to use install -g @angular/cli  ?  I had used at 5th point. Is it correct ?

Comment: This is a very poor question for stack overflow. Please don't post questions that show no effort to solve your own problems

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli` should be you first step because without installing it you can not run command `ng new ThirdApp`

Comment: And it requires only once

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your directory `cd ThirdApp` before `npm start`

Rather use `ng serve` for running your application on port 4200

Answer (score -3):

**$ npm init**

then reprocess whole commands, after that use

**$npm start**

try it